# SQL SERVER: What is the difference between PARSE, FORMAT, and CONVERT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion

I am trying to understand the idiosyncrasies and appropriate uses of PARSE vs. FORMAT vs. CONVERT in SQL Server 2014.

PARSE

```
PARSE ( string_value AS data_type [ USING culture ] )
```

FORMAT

```
FORMAT ( value, format, [ culture ] )
```

CONVERT

```
CONVERT(data_type(length),expression,style)
```

Seems like they are all similar, just different order of required arguments. And different format of arguments (e.g. CONVERT uses style codes while PARSE uses culture codes).

Comment: Check this out: http://sqlhints.com/tag/convert-vs-parse/

Comment: So now to start a discussion, hopefully, it seems like PARSE is like CONVERT on steroids. Why would you ever use CONVERT?

Also, does FORMAT then allow you to say, for example: FORMAT(DATETIME, 'Saturday, September 9th, 2010')?

Comment: Pretty sure this is not the right place for that discussion - this is a Q&A site, not a debate forum.

Comment: Sorry Mike, so what would you use to turn a standard DATETIME into a non-standard format?

Comment: @PabloBoswell Try it yourself using FORMAT and post a specific question if you get stuck.  CONVERT is there for backwards-compatibility - there may not be any need to use it unless you want to support SQL versions prior to 2012.

Comment: So running this query: SELECT FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, N'Saturday, January 1st, 2010') returns 'SaPur3a15, Januar15 128P, 2010'

Comment: @PabloBoswell That's not how `FORMAT` works - read the documentation and examples.

Comment: @DStanley I have looked at the documentation but they obviously don't show every single style option, so what is the general rule? I know you can do things like 'YYYY-MM-DD' or '00000000000', but is that it?

Comment: @PabloBoswell To answer your question you'd want `SELECT FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, N'dddd, MMM d, yyyy')`.  Note that there's no format specifier for `st`, `nd`, `rd`, etc.

Comment: You can find [Custom Date/Time Format strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 4):

[`PARSE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213316.aspx) and [`FORMAT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) were added to SQL 2012 for more precise parsing and string formatting.

`PARSE` and `FORMAT` are opposite operations (`PARSE` converts a string to another type; `FORMAT` converts a non-string type to a string using a specific format (e.g. currency, date-time).

[`CONVERT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) does limited conversions in either direction.  It still exists for backwards-compatibility.

Comment: I've edited your answer to include the links to the relevant MSDN pages. Hope you don't mind

Comment: I almost never edit someone else's answers, unless it's to add links to the reference, and I never change the text, not even to fix a spelling error. In this case, I was in the process of writing my own answer but you beat me by a minute, so I've already had the links open, so I figured what the hell, you can always rollback... Cheers.